# Java MVC Sentencias SQL que retornan campos de varias tablas

Tags: java, mvc

Tengo el siguiente método para acceder a los datos de dos tablas diferentes, estoy usando el patrón MVC y mi pregunta es si es correcto devolver un objeto ResultSet en este método y de ser así, de qué forma puedo acceder a los datos que contiene el ResultSet desde la vista.

Ya que lo que normalmente se hace es crear un ArrayList del objeto que yo retorne pero en este caso al estar retornando datos de dos tablas diferentes lo que haría sería retornar los datos de dos tipos de objeto diferentes si por ejemplo para la Tabla1 creara una clase en el modelo llamada Tabla1 y para la Tabla2 en el modelo creara una clase llamada Tabla2; entonces tendría que retornar objetos del tipo Tabla1 y objetos de tipo Tabla2; lo que se me ocurre en definitiva es retornar el resultset lo que no sé es cómo acceder cada uno de los campos que contenga el resultset desde la vista:

```
public ResultSet getProductos() throws Exception{


        Connection miConexion=null;
        Statement miStatement=null;
        ResultSet miResultSet=null;

        //----Establecer la conexion

        miConexion=origenDatos.getConnection();


        //-----Crear la sentencia sql
        String consulta="SELECT T1.Col1, T1.Col2, T1.Col3, T2.Col7 FROM Tabla1 T1 INNER JOIN Tabla2 T2 ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1";

        miStatement=miConexion.createStatement();
        //----Ejecutar la sentencia sql
        miResultSet=miStatement.executeQuery(consulta);

        //----Recorrer el ResultSet obtenido



        return miResultSet;
    }
```

Comment: Creo que la duda que tendrías que plantearte es ¿por qué si Tabla1 y Tabla2  devuelven datos relacionados tendrías que crear dos clases independientes para representar a cada tabla? A lo sumo, una clase debería extender de la otra o algo así. Creo que en tu planteamiento más que nada lo que puede haber es un error de diseño. Poco más se te podría decir, porque se desconoce el contexto. Pero supongamos que `T1` es la tabla `Persona`, y `T2` es la tabla `Profesor`, ¿no debería la clase `Profesor` extender de `Persona`? Así, mapearías tu `ResultSet` a la clase `Profesor`. Es sólo un ejemplo...

Answer (score 0):

Desde un punto de vista de separación de responsabilidad no es correcto retornar el resultSet al cliente de ese método. Podrías dependiendo del caso crear una nueva clase para representar los datos que retorna la consulta.